# Using DataViewRowState to assign styles to a DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a ReadOnly DataGridView bound to a bindingSource. There are other controls on the form that update the DataGridViewCells - they are databound to the bindingsource. I need to change the datagridviewCell styles based on what the DataViewRowState of the source is - .Current does not help me - what I need to do is track is the cell the original value - color the cell normal, if it is modified color it blue. I know I can get the DataRowViewState that gives me the version I am getting - but it always comes back current (as it is the default) and I do want the current - I just want to know if it differs from the original or not for this particular column. Since in my edit of the bindingsource I already have the row there does not appear to be an easy method or property that says this row is the original, or modified. Do I need to run a select using filterstates on the table to get my row and see if I get results back and then if so change the cell in order to do this ?

Relevant Code: - I know it is in VB.net but if you have c# example that is fine I do not care which - .net code is code and I can convert it.

```vb
Private Sub UpdateCellValue(columnName As String, textValue As String)

    If dgvBayList.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim crow As DataGridViewRow = dgvBayList.SelectedRows(0)
        Dim drv As DataRowView = DirectCast(bsBins.Current, DataRowView)

        If crow.Cells(columnName).Value = textValue Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        drv.BeginEdit()
        drv.Row.BeginEdit()
        drv.Row.SetField(Of String)(columnName, textValue)
        ' My Problem here is of course it is always original, 
        ' the row states of the Row always show Modified. 
        ' This happens when the binding source gets filled and bound to datagridview.

        Select Case drv.RowVersion
            Case DataRowVersion.Original
                Dim val As String = drv.Row(0).ToString()
                Exit Select
            Case DataRowVersion.Proposed
                Dim val As String = drv.Row(0).ToString()
                Exit Select
            Case DataRowVersion.Current
                Dim val As String = drv.Row(0).ToString()
                Exit Select
            Case DataRowVersion.Default
                Dim val As String = drv.Row(0).ToString()
                Exit Select
        End Select
        crow.Cells(columnName).Value = textValue
        drv.Row.EndEdit()
        drv.EndEdit()
        Dim dt As DataTable = sortingDataSet.bins

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that you need drv.Row.RowState  not drv.RowVersion

Comment: @Steve my RowState is always modified even before modification; I do not know why it is like this. The binding source is bound to a dataset.Table which gets filled on form load. Since it always declares modified from the get go - that does not help me. I also need to know if user changed it back to original - I want it to look like a normal unchanged cell. I am thinking I am going to need to select using rowfilter - there should be an easier way. I hope there is one.

Comment: If I look at `RowState` in the cell formatting event, it works fine for me.

Comment: @Plutonix - when I look at it in cell formatting event it shows rowstate modified - my binding source rows show modified (all I have done is load the datagridview from a dataset and nothing more), if the form user changes the value back - it should not say modified either. I am programatically editing directly in the bindingsource datasource and not in the datagridview. However I have found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050837/how-can-i-get-a-specific-version-of-a-dataset-row which might be of some help - I can compare original with current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the comments and using different thoughts to search I found a SO answer that provided part of the solution [How can I get a specific version of a dataset row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050837/how-can-i-get-a-specific-version-of-a-dataset-row).

In order to implement that solution , I needed to set up a mechanism for calling a generic function where T was unknown until run time. After looking again on SO - I found some good answers for that; [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method) .

Below is the final code I use From my controls changed value to implement the changes to the datagridview and apply styles to the individual cells based on Original or Proposed values.

```
Private Sub UpdateCellValue(Of T)(columnName As String, value As T)

    If dgvBayList.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then

        Dim crow As DataGridViewRow = dgvBayList.SelectedRows(0)

        Dim drv As DataRowView = DirectCast(bsDataSource.Current, DataRowView)

        If crow.Cells(columnName).Value = value Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        drv.BeginEdit()

        drv.Row.BeginEdit()

        drv.Row.SetField(Of T)(columnName, value)

        crow.Cells(columnName).Value = value

        Dim objType As Type = drv.Row(columnName).GetType()

        Dim method As Reflection.MethodInfo = _
                 Me.GetType().GetMethod("SetDataGridViewCellStyle", _
                 Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or _ 
                 Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or _
                 Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)

        Dim GenericSetDataGridViewCellStyle As Reflection.MethodInfo = _
                                               method.MakeGenericMethod(objType)

        Dim parms As Object() = {crow.Cells(columnName), drv, columnName}

        GenericSetDataGridViewCellStyle.Invoke(Me, parms)

        drv.Row.EndEdit()
        drv.EndEdit()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SetDataGridViewCellStyle(Of T) ( _
                             cell As DataGridViewCell, _
                             dRowView As DataRowView, _ 
                             columnName As String)

    Dim nothingness As Integer = 0

    If dRowView.Row.Field(Of T)(columnName, DataRowVersion.Original) Is Nothing Then
        nothingness += 1
    End If

    If dRowView.Row.Field(Of T)(columnName, DataRowVersion.Current) Is Nothing Then
        nothingness += 1
    End If

    If nothingness = 0 Then

        Dim original As T = dRowView.Row.Field(Of T)(columnName, DataRowVersion.Original)
        Dim current As T = dRowView.Row.Field(Of T)(columnName, DataRowVersion.Current)
        Dim proposed As T = dRowView.Row.Field(Of T)(columnName, DataRowVersion.Proposed)

        If EqualsCompare(Of T)(original, proposed) Then   

            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.White)

        Else

            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Fuchsia)

        End If

    Else
        If nothingness = 2 Then

            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.White)
        Else
            ' cell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Fuchsia)'
        End If

    End If

    cell.DataGridView.Update()

End Sub

Public Shared Function EqualsCompare(Of T)(a As T, b As T) As Boolean

    Return EqualityComparer(Of T).[Default].Equals(a, b)

End Function
```

And I call it like this

```
UpdateCellValue(Of Boolean)("kickingIt", True)
```

Relevant links that helped me

[How can I get a specific version of a dataset row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050837/how-can-i-get-a-specific-version-of-a-dataset-row)

[How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)